# No, I am NOT a robot!

Tags: discussion

I have 39K reputation.  How can the site even THINK about asking if I am a robot?!  I haven't been a robot for the past god knows how many years (as far as I know).

And the Capcha (is that how you spell the stupid word) is unusable on a small screen.  Having to identify what is in pictures when the pictures are too small to make out what they are supposed to be is just idiotic!  How am I supposed to identify which of those little brown blobs is supposed to be a hamburger?!

Surely that sort of thing should never ever happen for a known human(ish) user.  A new user, yes, but one with 39k reputation?!

Comment: It just asked me again while posting this question. How idiotic is that? I wasn't a robot last time, and I sure as hell am not a robot this time!

Comment: The system is attempting to make sure your account hasn't been hacked.

Comment: Twice in a row?  It's never done it before so why now?  Is it because I happen to be using a different browser right at this moment that yesterday?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's one sign that the person attempting to use your account might not be you. Different browser, different IP address, different machine, etc.

Comment: I jumo around between machines and browsers all the time. Computer, laptops, phone, etc, and never before has it worried about it.  I don't mind that it's being cautious, but the captcheurgh is unworkable on a smaller screen (like a tablet or phone) since it is impossible to see what the pictures are meant to be.

Comment: You can't zoom in? That's unusual.

Comment: Not on the system I am working on right at this moment, no.  It's not your normal Android or IOS crud, but an embedded Linux system.

Comment: So, bottom line: You're just ranting because the system happened to do something that's a little bit inconvenient on the oddball, nonstandard system you're using at the moment. Get over it.

Comment: I have also been pegged as a "possible robot" a lot more often lately - it seems like it's a network-wide thing, not just EE:SE.

Comment: Maybe we've been hanging around Olin too much....

Comment: Wow, this question shows how advanced robots have become so that they don't even realize themselves they are robots.  The fiction of *Blade Runner* has turned to fact faster than I thought.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Captcha run amok](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/captcha-run-amok)

Comment: @OlinLathrop  The plot of the *Blade Runner* takes place in 2019.  Voight-Kampff test, anyone?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I'll get my pet owl to take it....